# Convert private paid project to free private in Assembla

Tags: project, assembla

I have a private project in Assembla with Starter plan, how can i convert this project to free private(non-public) project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to the Admin tab of your space and check if there's an option to do that directly.

If you will see the statement `Remove this space from your Starter Package and convert it into a Free Private space` - just click it to convert the space to Free/Private.

Please be aware that all your Professional (paid) tools will be deleted in that case (Messages, Files, StandUp, Milestones, Tickets, Wiki, Time, GitHub, Support, FTP, Webhook, Custom Tabs).

If you will see `Remove this space from your Starter Package and convert it into a free public space` - then you have an option to convert the space to Free/Public only.

In that case the only option to convert it to Free/Private would be to back up the data in your space (via Admin > Resources tab of your space or Import/Export subtab of your Source/SVN and the Settings page of the Tickets tools) and then create a new Free/Private space and import the dump files there.